# CSS: resize div width according to parents width

Tags: html, css, css-float, fluid-layout

Ok, I am basically building a fluid layout.
My HTML is like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box" id="left">Left</div>
    <div class="box" id="center">This text is long and can get longer</div>
    <div class="box" id="right">Right</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
}
.box{
    float: left;
}
#left, #right{
    width: 100px;
}
#center{
    width: auto; /* ? */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

What I need to know is how do I get the `#center` to re-size when `#container` is re-sized without the elements moving underneath each other.

Comment: just a simple correction: <div class="box" id="centre">This text is long and can get longer</div> the id is "center" ;)

Comment: cheers, I cant believe I did that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these corrections (just simple floating elements, no need to set absolute elems or paddings)

[just added a new fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/GXjUD/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>fluid layout</title>
<style>
    /*class to set the width of the columns */
    .floatbox{
        width:100px;
    }

    #container{
        width: 100%;
        float:left;
    }
    #left{
        float:left;
    }
    #right{
        float:right;
    }
    #center{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .clear{
        clear:both;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- floating column to the right, it must be placed BEFORE the left one -->
        <div class="floatbox" id="right">Right</div>
        <div class="floatbox" id="left">Left</div>

        <!-- central column, it takes automatically the remaining width, no need to declare further css rules -->
        <div id="center">This text is long and can get longer</div>

        <!-- footer, beneath everything, css is ok -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`#container` also must be floated (or with overflow: auto/hidden) to achieve it.
I strongly suggest you use some of the more well known fluid solutions: http://www.noupe.com/css/9-timeless-3-column-layout-techniques.html

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this and completely avoid the `float` issues that arise would be to 
use padding on the container and absolute position the left/right elements in the padding area. (*demo at  http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/8gKWq/1*)

**Html**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box" id="left">Left</div>
    <div class="box" id="right">Right</div>
    <div class="box" id="centre">This text is long and can get longer</div>
</div>
```

The order of the divs does not matter anymore..

**Css**

```
#container{
    padding:0 100px;
    position:relative;
}
.box{
   /*style the boxes here*/
}
#left, #right{
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
}
#left{left:0;top:0;}
#right{right:0;top:0;}

#center{
   /*anything specific to the center box should go here.*/
}
```